# How to use Ffmpeg in android studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-studio

I want to compress video and found only one solution to use ffmpeg.

I found this [Trying to use FFMPEG for android. Compiling but still not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871144/trying-to-use-ffmpeg-for-android-compiling-but-still-not-working) but not able to get how he compiled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use precompiled libs from the [JavaCPP Presets](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/) along with `FFmpegFrameRecorder` from [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) to compress images, as shown in the [RecordActivity sample](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java), for example.