# How to use latest FFMPEG in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, video, android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have a simple task to make a video from multiple images and an audio file, After searching a lot found that its possible with FFMPEG, Unfortunately there are no updated tutorials for FFMPEG, there are few but outdated and most of them are not working.
As I have compiled FFMPEG for Android using NDK android-ndk-r10e and ffmpeg-2.8.6 on my MAC with Android Studio following the tutorial http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/
It makes the .so files as
[image: files generated from ffmpeg]

Now I can't understand what should I do to integrate this in my Android project, I have also checked,

[How to use Ffmpeg in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933189/how-to-use-ffmpeg-in-android-studio)

[how to use ffmpeg in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459648/how-to-use-ffmpeg-in-android)

[FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

and mainly this,

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/

https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial

But its not working and having errors with no way to resolve this. Can anyone please mention some steps that should be followed to use FFMPEG .so files as in image attached.

Comment: Can you please share steps to create so file from ffmpeg lib.

Comment: hey buddy have you get any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a very easy solution for this, There's a precompiled library for android, as below https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
Simply include this as a gradle project in your code and add few methods as per their documentation and you are done with FFMPEG commands in android. 
This library is not very updated and have some missing features but still its good to use for many simple tasks.

Comment: I have tried this suggested lib, but its not working for higher versions, as it failed in Lollipop

Comment: @King You sure ? Cause i have used this for developing an application that works even on Marshmallow 6.0.

Comment: if you want to use pre compiled lib see this https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android `Uses FFmpeg release n4.0-39-gda39990`