# How can i add watermark to video in android studio with library

Tags: android, watermark, android-ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I want to add a watermark to a video. so that when user select a video from gallery in the android studio. then watermark will be added to the video automatically like this.
Please check the image that how i want to add watermark logo to a video with auto adjust logo size according to the video.

[image]

Or when user will download a video then a watermark will be added to the videos. i have searched a lot but not found any library for adding watermark to a video. I have found something with FFMPEG but not working in android studio. so please provide me a library or a way to add watermark to a video.

Comment: `I have found something with FFMPEG but not working in android studio` FFMPEG certainly works with "Android Studio". You could start by checking how this works: https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Comment: I have checked this library. but not able to understand how can i add logo to a video. so do you have any other suggestion for library. that will be easy to use and convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very easy solution for this, There's a precompiled library for android, as below https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java Simply include this as a gradle project in your code and add few methods as per their documentation and you are done with FFMPEG commands in android. This library is not very updated and have some missing features but still its good to use for many simple tasks.

source: [how to use latest FFMPEG in android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36280656/11691547)

you can find a tutorial about using this library at the following link:

[Integrate FFMpeg (Video Editor) Library using Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJDV40lAtJg)

Comment: Not working showing permission denied for the soundtrack and also where i have to add watermark logo in this

Comment: It's not answered the actual query. Not even mentioned the command to watermark too.

Comment: there isn't any good resource about using this library, but you can figure it out by reading the actual code, about resolving the FFMPEG code, you need to search about FFMPEG commands https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: this is how you can import the FFMPEG into Android studio project, if you need to know how to work with FFMPEG you need to refer to documentation