# Add a image as a watermark while recording a video and saving a video with watermark in android c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Add a image as a watermark while recording a video and saving a video with watermark in Android C#. I am using `MediaRecorder` for record a video.

Comment: by my search, I find the FFmpeg may help you to add watermark in video, here is the thread that you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750430/how-can-i-add-watermark-to-video-in-android-studio-with-library

Comment: this is for android studio, but im asking for xamarin.android c#. not for cross platform.native in xamarin. Can u please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO karthi. You would have to create Native C# binding of that library that Cherry shared about. This is a good tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/